# Create new record based on old one

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, crud, activescaffold

I'm newbie here and I'm building CRUD app on Ruby on Rails ( ruby 2.1.5, rails 4.1.6 ) with ActiveScaffold (latest from git repo). I've done CRUD actions successfully, but now I want to create new record, based on old record to improve speed of filling.
How can I add "edit and create new" link to the right (where show and delete links located, that will create new record with same fields as in selected record, so I can fast edit some fields (date for example) and create new record?

Answer (score 0):

Eureka! All that I need was active_scaffold_duplicate gem.
Also some search by word "duplicate" in ActiveScaffold group. Sorry for such easy question, my brain needs to relax :)